# ¿Como guardar una imagen en la base de datos Laravel?

Tags: laravel, migration

Buenas Estoy haciendo un proyecto donde los usuarios pueden alquilar películas , por lo cual quiero  mostrar una imagen de la película junto a los demás datos de la película , pero no se en que tipo de dato debo guardar la imagen en la base de datos o no es recomendable guardar imágenes en la base de datos ? y de ser asi como podria guardar una imagen para poderlo mostrar con mis peliculas.

**Tabla Peliculas que tengo hasta el momento(aun no he hecho la migracion)**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('peliculas', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('nombre_pelicula' , 30);
            $table->string('autor_pelicula' , 30);
            $table->string('genero_pelicula' , 30);
            $table->text('descripcion_pelicula' , 30);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: si es para guardar la dirección de donde se almacena la imagen, entonces como un campo tipo string basta

Comment: @element realmente no se como debo guardarla , si la direccion donde se almacena o guardarla en la base de datos directamente , nunca he trabajado con imaganes en la base de datos .

Comment: ahora si quieres almacenar como tal el archivo, entonces tal vez un dato de tipo blob que su equivalente en laravel es `$table->binary('data');`

Comment: @element pero cual es la mejor manera ,guardar la direccion donde se almacena o guardarla en la base de datos directamente?

Comment: Hola Neiider, mira... en este tema hay opiniones divididas. Creo que la mayoría se inclina a la opinión de que guardar la imagen en la DB se debe dejar como ultimo recurso. Yo particularmente comparto esta opinión. En la documentancion de Laravel puedes encontrar como guardarla en una carpeta del servidor simplemente.Sino puedes buscar tutoriales en Internet y vas a encontrar muchos respecto a este tema. Me parece lo mas fácil y correcto. Saludos!

Comment: Esto te puede servir [Laravel blob](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/web-development/threads/480731/how-to-inserting-files-on-mysql-using-laravel)

Comment: Personalmente recomiendo que guardes las imagenes en disco para ello usar un campo tipo string en tu bd y referencia la ruta de esa imagen. Si guardas la imagen en la base de datos estarias consumiendo mucho recursos de bd.